# Execute specific vbs file from batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Batch content:

```
echo Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
<nul set /p =wshshell.sendkeys ^"^<nul set ^/p ^=>>"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
Type "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.txt">>"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
echo {bs}^>^"^"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.txt^"^"{enter}^">>"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
wscript "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
```

The vbs generated is:

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshshell.sendkeys "<nul set /p =La#{bs}>""C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.txt""{enter}"
```

The prova.txt contains:

```
La#
```

After execute this line from new command prompt session:

```
wscript "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
```

The prova.txt becomes

```
La
```

But if execute the same line as above from batch:

```
wscript "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
```

nothing happens!

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: cannot reproduce. Can you create a [mcve] without all the hardcoded paths so everyone can see your problem?

Comment: Hello. In short, I need to execute my.vbs files via a batch file.
In command prompt the code:
wscript "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
It works, but in batch does not work

Comment: Wow, a batch script to create a VBScript to "type" a batch command via `SendKeys` (using `set /p` for writing to a file no less). That's one of the most hideous things I've seen in quite a while. Please erase all traces of this abomination and start over. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The entire code works.
The problem is that by batch the code:
wscript "C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs"
it does not work but it works only by opening the prompt and type manually

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers on this one, there's better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: We don't put SOLVED into the title here. Instead, mark an answer as accepted, or if none is suitable provide your own answer so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call the script like so:

```
C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\prova.vbs
```

If that doesn't work, change directory to your desktop, and call the `vbs`:

```
cd C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\
prova.vbs
```

That should work in a batch file.

Comment: Does not work. I embarked on another solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am solved the my problem. The "Prova.bat" code is:

```
echo Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>prova.vbs
echo wshShell.Run "cmd">>prova.vbs
echo WScript.Sleep 250>>prova.vbs
<nul set /p =wshShell.sendkeys ^"^<nul set ^/p ^=>>prova.vbs
Type prova.txt>>prova.vbs
<nul set /p ={bs}^>prova.txt{enter}exit{enter}^">>prova.vbs
wscript prova.vbs
DEL /q prova.vbs 2> NUL
```

The "Prova.vbs" generated and deleted is:

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 250
wshShell.sendkeys "<nul set /p =La#8{bs}>prova.txt{enter}exit{enter}"
```

The "Prova.txt" before:

```
La#8
```

The "Prova.txt" now:

```
La#
```

I am found the way of insert backspace character in a txt file using bat+vbs file! ;-) I hope that such a solution can be of help to someone else.